# Add a popup legal notice to a website

Tags: javascript, html

The website https://www.abeille-cyclotourisme.fr is made by hand. Not with Wordpress or any PHP-type database.

Four days ago, I got on this forum the solution for a non-popup legal notice, on the thread "Add a legal notice".

Earlier thread : [Add a legal notice to a website made of separate pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282663/add-a-legal-notice-to-a-website-made-of-separate-pages)

I transformed the script in such a way that the legal notice would open on a separate window.

The script, in the "scripts" folder at root, is written as follows:

```
/* "Contactez nous"
    Crée un message comportant l'adresse mail de l'abeille
    et un texte dans le champ objet
*/

// Fonction htmlWindow_600 

  function htmlWindow_600(pagehtml) {
       htmlWindow = window.open(pagehtml, "minifenetre", "toolbar=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=600,height=440")
       htmlWindow.focus()
  }

// D&eacute;finition d'une variable contenant le d&eacute;but du code HTML

var liencontact="<a href='mailto:";

/* Ajout des diff&eacute;rents &eacute;l&eacute;ments de l'adresse mail
   dans la variable
*/
liencontact +="abeille-cyclotourisme";
liencontact +="@";
liencontact +="abeille-cyclotourisme.fr";
liencontact +="?subject=%5BAbeille%5D%20Demande%20d%27information'>";

// Affichage du lien vers "notice" et du lien mail 

document.write("<a href='https://www.abeille-cyclotourisme.fr/notice.html' target='lien'>Notice<\/a> - "+liencontact+"Contactez-nous @<\/a>");
```

I want it to open in a popup window which is narrower than the standard page, in such a way that the visitor would *see right away that he is in a popup. Narrower ? I chose a 600px width for all popup windows of the site: all html popups use the script htmlwindow_600.

Why a popup ? Because a legal notice is a dead end. No link starts from it while I want it to be reachable from any page - More precisely from any page's footer. Making it as a plain page, as I have so far, looks weird, because once you are on the legal notice, you want to move away from it. Shutting down the popup seems to me like the cleanest solution, but others may object.

BTW: why a legal notice in a bicycle website ? Because we will start collecting names for pre-registrations to events we organise and believe we must (1) show respect to our visitors and (2) offer protection to the bicycle club and directors.

I have written the language of the htmlWindow_600 script in the script language above, as an information and to facilitate my tests, but not succeeded to use it, or any other script opening a narrower window.

I have tried:

```
document.write("<a href='https://www.abeille-cyclotourisme.fr/notice.html' target='lien' onclick='javascript:htmlWindow_600('https://www.abeille-cyclotourisme.fr/notice.html');return false'>Notice - <\/a>"+liencontact+"Contactez-nous @<\/a>");
```

Using standard html, it opens a new window on click on "Notice", but it fails to open a popup using the function htmlWindow_600. How could I cure this ? TIA

Comment: What is the purpose of a popup for a "legal notice"?

Comment: Why not read it: https://www.abeille-cyclotourisme.fr/notice.html

Comment: @mplungjan, you mean use AJAX to create an XHR request to grab the HTML content from the document itself to render it to the dialog?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes. A jQuery .load type thing or in an iframe

Answer (score 0):

It should work if popups are allowed. A better solution would be to use a dialog which does not need a permission to be shown.

Anyway, try this - your quotes needs to be escaped but I managed to avoid that by passing the href:

NOTE: Neither link will work here since one is a mailto and the other a popup, neither of which are allowed to run in the stacksnippet sandbox

```js
var liencontact="<a href='mailto:";

/* Ajout des diff&eacute;rents &eacute;l&eacute;ments de l'adresse mail
   dans la variable
*/
liencontact +="abeille-cyclotourisme";
liencontact +="@";
liencontact +="abeille-cyclotourisme.fr";
liencontact +="?subject=%5BAbeille%5D%20Demande%20d%27information'>";

document.write("<a href='https://www.abeille-cyclotourisme.fr/notice.html' target='lien'"+ 
" onclick='return htmlWindow_600(this.href)'>[Notice]</a> [" + liencontact + "Contactez-nous @</a>]");

function htmlWindow_600(pagehtml) {
  var htmlWindow = window.open(pagehtml, "minifenetre", "toolbar,status,menubar,location,scrollbars,resizable,width=600,height=440");
  if (htmlWindow) {
    htmlWindow.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true; // this will open the rejected popup in a normal tab instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mplungjan mentioned popups are not the best solution.  I recommend that you use a modal as you will be able to design it to suit your site.  A very simple example is provided on the w3schools site here: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp

If your legal notice is long you could have a scrolling div or even an iframe to a separate page with the legal notice inside of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I tried to reply to guest271314 in an edit to my original post.

garrettlynch suggested the use of a modal. I did not know what a modal was, what CSS3 was. I will learn that as it may be immensely useful to remove all of the popups which exist, for reasons I believe are worth respecting, on the current website.

A side note to garrettlynch and mplungjian: I agree javascript is to be avoided and popups are to be avoided. At least, all current popups on the website are degradable (if javascript is "off", they still perform in html) and all current javascript is degradable to html.

mplungjian then suggested a cure to my poor javascript and made it degradable as well. mplungjian cure works, perfectly. Great ! this will do for the time being. Then I will learn what I need to learn about CSS3 and modals.

Thank-you very much to all of you.